# Dynamic scatter plot - Visualforce & HighCharts.js

Tags: apex, visualforce

This [scatter plot](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/scatter) is really interesting to me. Amending the code to reference static data is easy but how would one go about making this scatter plot dynamic to display all the opportunities by closed month and amount?

Let's say the x axis is to show the 12 months of the year (Jan - Dec) and the y axis is the amount of the opportunity. I am getting stuck on how to pass in a method that would result in all opportunities being populated in the scatter plot dynamically. The below does not work.

```
public static List<Double> getoppInfoAmount() {
        List<Double> amountXList = new List<Double>(); 
        Double amountX;
        for (Opportunity opp : oppList) {
             amountX = opp.Amount; 
             amountXList.add(amountX);
        }
        return amountXList;  
    }

    public static List<Date> getoppInfoDate() {
        List<Date> dateXList = new List<Date>(); 
        Date dateX;
        for (Opportunity opp : oppList) {
            dateX = opp.CloseDate;
            dateXList.add(dateX);
        }
        return dateXList;
    }

 name: 'APAC',
            color: 'rgba(103, 159, 37, 0.5)',
            data: [[{!oppInfoAmount}], [{!oppInfoDate}]
                }]
```

---

Edit: Update as of 18th August:

Here is the VF page:

```
<apex:page controller="ScatterPlotTest">


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>    
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 800px; margin: 0 auto"></div>


<script>
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'scatter',
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Scatter Plot Graph'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: Salesforce - Closed Won Opportunities YTD'
        },
        xAxis: {
            title: {
                enabled: true,
                text: 'Height (cm)'
            },
            startOnTick: true,
            endOnTick: true,
            showLastLabel: true
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Weight (kg)'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'left',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: 100,
            y: 70,
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF',
            borderWidth: 1
        },
        plotOptions: {
            scatter: {
                marker: {
                    radius: 5,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            enabled: true,
                            lineColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
                        }
                    }
                },
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        marker: {
                            enabled: false
                        }
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
                    pointFormat: '{point.x} cm, {point.y} kg'
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Female',
            color: 'rgba(223, 83, 83, .5)',
            data: [[{!OppList}[0], {!OppList}[1]] 
        }]
    });
});


</script>

</apex:page>
```

And here is the Class:

```
public class ScatterPlotTest {

    public static final Id oppNBRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Opportunity.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('New Business - Read Only').getRecordTypeId();
    public static final Set<String> stages = new Set<String>{'Closed Won', 'Closed Won & Billed'};
    public static List<Opportunity> oppList = [SELECT Amount, ExpectedRevenue FROM Opportunity WHERE RecordTypeId =:oppNBRecordTypeId AND StageName =:stages AND Once_off_fee__c = false AND Billing_Effective_Date__c = THIS_YEAR];


    public String getOppList() {
    List<List<Object>> results = new List<List<Object>>();
    for(Opportunity record: oppList) {
        List<Object> result = new List<Object>(2); 
        result[0] = record.Amount;
        result[1] = record.ExpectedRevenue;
        results.add(result);
        System.debug(results);
    }
    return JSON.serialize(results);
}
}
```

By calling the Class method, I can see the results in the debug log:

[image]

However, as per the below screenshot, this doesn't render properly in the VF page:

[image]

Comment: Is this code *exactly* as you've written it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, your data won't work this way. You're basically shoving a bunch of random text that will get the default serialization into your JavaScript, which is why it doesn't work. Instead, consider JSONifying your data:

```
public String getOppList() {
    List<List<Object>> results = new List<List<Object>>();
    for(Opportunity record: oppList) {
        List<Object> result = new List<Object>(2);
        result[0] = record.Amount;
        result[1] = record.CloseDate;
        results.add(result);
    }
    return JSON.serialize(results);
}
```

This will present your data something like this:

```
[[1234,"2016-09-02"],[2345,"2016-08-17"]...]
```

At which point, you can drop it right in place of what you're trying to do:

```
name: 'APAC',
color: 'rgba(103, 159, 37, 0.5)',
data: {!oppList},
```

---

Based on your code, oppList should be used as follows:

```
series: [{ name: 'Female', 
                 color: 'rgba(223, 83, 83, .5)', 
                 data: {!oppList} }]
```

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, I updated my answer with the full code I am working with. Thanks a lot for your previous response. Do you have any ideas how I can get my code to work? It may be to do with HighCharts itself, as the class is working correctly it seems.

Comment: @AndyHitchings you're close. Try my edited update.

Comment: one last thing, do you know how I can get the CloseDate to render in Date format on the X axis? At the moment, it's just printing out the indexes along the X axis. I have looked at HighCharts documentation and added xAxis: type: 'datetime' but no luck. The method has the CloseDate for the X axis like so:  List<Object> result = new List<Object>(2);    result[0] = record.CloseDate;  result[1] = record.Amount;

Comment: @AndyHitchings try date instead? There's no time component on the output, I believe. I'd have to check the output though.

Comment: Yes, I used type: 'date' too but no luck. Thanks